# Jenkins Deployment on Kubernetes has a problem with logs

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I made a Jenkins Deployment on Kubernetes. It works fine but when I try to show container logs an error occurs.

```
$ kubectl logs jenkins-5b587f57b8-tfz2f
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 10):

Good working [solution](https://www.thoutam.com/2018/08/13/jenkins-copy_reference_file-log-permission-denied-issue-in-k8s/) i found is adding a [Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/):

```
securityContext:
 fsGroup: 1000 
 runAsUser: 0
```

to Jenkins Deployment spec.